# Showing that the Directed Polymer (DP) partition function satisfies the Feynman Kac equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function

> Knowing that the DP model has the partition function:
>   $$Z_x(h)=\int_{0,0}^{x,h}\mathcal{D}[h'] \exp\left(-\frac{1}{T}\int_0^xdx'\left[\frac{\nu}{2}( \partial_{x'} h')^2+V(x',h') \right] \right).$$
>   Applying the appropriate derivatives should be enough to show that $Z$ satisfies:
>   $$\frac{\partial Z_x(h)}{\partial x}=\frac{T}{2\nu}\frac{\partial^2Z}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{T}V(x,h)Z_x(h).$$

However, I have no clue on how to operate the derivatives in the limit of integration of a functional integration. Does anyone know how to apply these derivatives. Also, I would appreciate a link to a web site where this kind of functional calculus subject is explained.